# How to get liblua5.1-0-dev for Windows 7?

Tags: mingw, windows-7-x64, libvlc, msys, luac

I'm trying to compile VLC source code on a 64-bits Windows 7 machine. When running the configure file, it gives me an error message saying "configure: error: You need 32-bits luac when using using lua from contrib". So I searched it up on the Internet and one post indicates that liblua5.1-0-dev:i386 is needed to get it work. However, all of liblua-dev files are for linux as I've seen so far. (I can't use apt-get since it's not supported by msys)

So I'm wondering is there any way I can download a Windows version of liblua-dev? Or is there an alternative way to solve my problem?

Any help is appreciated here. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Just wanna follow up that I figured it out. What I did is in addition to build contrib with target x86_64-w64-mingw32, I also built it with i686-w64-ming32(for 32 bit windows) and copied luac.exe to replace the one in the 64-bits bin folder. Everything works fine now.